# VisualSVN Server repository move

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I have my repository folder placed on my external drive. Now I have to change drive to the other one. Can I just copy over that folder to other drive and how then VisualSVN Server manager should connect to it?

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the directory with your repositories to another storage,
2. Point VisualSVN Server to the new location of your repositories:
   **VisualSVN Server Manager | Action | Properties | Storage**.
3. [Make sure that permissions are correct on the new repositories location](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/).